# orange pi one, os armbian(без рабочего стола)

Tags: orange-pi, armbian-linux

Как подключиться удаленно к orange pi one. Например если был бы рабочий стол, можно было бы софт какой-нибудь скачать. Как подключиться, если ОС без рабочего стола? Надеюсь поняли что имею ввиду

Answer (score 0):

ssh. https://docs.armbian.com/User-Guide_Getting-Started/

Логин root пароль 1234, если не сменил. Берешь putty и подключайся.

Если нужны окошки то по аналогии такой инструкции  https://m.habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/510860/

Comment: ну так это локально же, нет? Локально все работает, я использую ssh и putty. А как мне с любой точки мира подключиться к нему

Comment: @Jenka если ip адрес на роутере не начинается с цифр 10, 100, 172, 192 то нужно включить дднс на роутере и пробрость порт.

Comment: https://tmate.io/ програмку поставь если нет возможности пробросить порт

Comment: Да и в вопросе ничего про удаленно